# Direction of Current Flow in the circuit?

Tags: power-supply, dc

I'm a little bit confused with the current flow in the given power supply circuit.

[image]

- Does D3 conduct when D1 conducts in the positive half cycle?
- Could someone explain direction of current flow through the diodes and regulators in each half cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bridge rectifier. Basically, for both the positive and negative parts of the sinusoid waveform, the current will always flow through the load in the same direction. D1 and D3 conduct together, and D2 and D4 conduct together. The capacitors smooth out the ripples in the waveforms.

[image: Bridge Rectifier, with colours!]

Comment: I tried the circuit with 12-0-12 transformer instead of 6-0-6 ,but i'm getting -8v from the 7905 out,7805 is Ok. what would be the possible cause?

Comment: Using a 12-0-12 transformer will give (12*sqrt(2))-1.4 = 15.6V across each 5V regulator. This is in-spec for the datasheets I saw, however these devices WILL get hot when the load starts to draw current. Example: 10V*500mA (example, cellphone USB charger) = 5W of power each. In comparison, 6 - 0 - 6 will only need to drop 2V/regulator and 2*500mA = 1W. As for why the 7905 isn't working, Look at your pin configuration to see if it's right, double check that the input voltage is within spec, and consider that the 7905 might just be damaged in some way.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, D1 and D3 conduct at the same time, as do D4 and D2.

This configuration of diodes is so common it has a name, which is *full wave bridge*.  You often see it drawn in a diamond shape as in your schematic, but I like to draw it differently to avoid exactly the confusion you are having.

Here is a better way to visualize a full wave bridge:

[image]

Imagine these are perfect diodes for now.  Regardless of the polarity of the AC signal, the more positive AC line will make one of the top diodes conduct, and the more negative one of the bottom.  Hopefully you can see how this effectively takes the absolute value of that AC input voltage.

Real diodes have forward voltage drops.  If we figure 700 mV for these ordinary silicon diodes, then the AC signal has to have a magnitude of 1.4 V before anything conducts to the output.

Answer (score 2):

This type of power supply does tend to benefit from a balanced load on positive and negative outputs. If this is the case then D3 conducts when D1 conducts (one half cycle) and D4 conducts when D2 conducts (on the other half cycle).

If the load is imbalanced then things are similar. Let's say there is no load on the negative regulator and if this is the case the conduction of the diodes is still the same BUT the centre-tap of the transformer acts as the return path for currents. With a balanced load there is no current in or out of the centre-tap.

Generally with these types of regulators, current flows from left to right on the 7805 and right to left on the 7905. The ground connections are needed for correct operation and they take a few milli-amps irrespective of load.

Also note that I think you may have a pin number discrepancy on your regulators - they both cannot be numbered the same.